# create-react-app and JavaScript dependency that is using async/await fails to compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Steps to reproduce:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app demo-app
cd demo-app
npm install --save instascan
# add `import Instascan from 'instascan'` to index.js
npm start
```

Error message:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/instascan/src/camera.js
Module parse failed: /Users/rd/code/instascan-react/node_modules/instascan/src/camera.js Unexpected token (13:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:8)
 @ ./~/instascan/index.js 6:10-33

Error in ./~/instascan/src/scanner.js
Module parse failed: /Users/rd/code/instascan-react/node_modules/instascan/src/scanner.js Unexpected token (208:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (208:8)
 @ ./~/instascan/index.js 5:11-35
```

Further inspection show that calls to `async` are found at camera.js:13 and scanner.js:208. The create-react-app docs say that async/await is supported, but maybe this isn't enabled for dependencies?

I'm not sure what to try next. Any guidance here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working as expected.

Create React App only compiles *your* code to ES5 (which browsers and the minifier can understand) but not the code of your dependencies. Otherwise it would be much slower (and it also breaks some libraries).

You can file an issue with the library that is shipping uncompiled code, and ask them to compile it to ES5 before publishing to npm. This is generally the recommended practice, and most libraries supporting browser usage do that.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the info.